# Spring JPA Specification - sort precedence

Tags: java, spring, sorting, jpa, spring-data-jpa

lets say that you use `JpaSpecificationExecutor` to execute a paged `Specification`. You end up having sort

1. on `CriteriaQuery` in `Specification::toPredicate`
2. on `Pageable`s `Sort` property

What's the effective sorting?

```java
class Car {
   Long id;
   String make;
   String model;
   String color;
}

class CarRepository {

   private JpaSpecificationExecutor<Car> specExecutor;

   Page<Car> fetchAllCars() {
      Specification<Car> spec = (r,q,cb) -> {
         // 1. Sort on CriteriaQuery itself
         q.orderBy(cb.asc("make"));
         q.orderBy(cb.asc("model"));
         return cb.conjunction();
      };

      // 2. Sort on Pageable
      Sort sort = Sort.by(
          Sort.Order.desc("id"), 
          Sort.Order.desc("color")
      );
      return specExecutor.findAll(spec, PageRequest.of(0, 10, sort));
   }
}
```

Comment: Basing on sources I believe that both sortings are applied. One from `CriteriaQuery` first, then one from `Pageable`. So in the example above effective sorting should be `make asc, model asc, id desc, color desc`.